# kde with no root window

Tags: kde, plasma

I wish to disable the kde root window, so I can see the X11 root window. I have seen, in lots of places how to do this for older/newer versions of kde, but I can not get it to work on mine.

I am running Debian Gnu/Linux in virtual box, I wish to use seemless mode. However because kde has its own root window over the X11 root window, the transparency is not working. It is covering the host windows.

I have discovered that plasma-destop does the background and panels. Don't know how to get it to do just panels.

---

```
#>uname -a
Linux richard-laptop 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux
#>kwin --version
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Qt: 4.8.2
KDE Development Platform: 4.8.4 (4.8.4)
KWin: 4.8.4 (4.8.4)
```